# Service Bus Local Dev

Tags: c#, azure, rabbitmq, azureservicebus

I'm aware a lot of people have asked about Azure Service Bus local development story and I'm familiar that Microsoft don't provide an on premise solution at the moment. I have also familiarised myself with Jimmy Bogart's writings on the matter.

I have a variation on the repeated question which I think hasn't been answered before. I have a legacy codebase that is using the older service bus API `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient` which cannot be easily changed. I also am unable to stub the dependency.

Ideally I'd like to use something like RabbitMQ on-prem for local dev. I was thinking they both can use AMQP v1.0 protocol. Is it possible to force the Service Bus client to use RabbitMQ (or similar) as an AMQP endpoint with the `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient` class just with changing the connection string - as a replacement for the ASB dependency? (all I need to support is deferal of messages)

Appreciate this use case is a little bizarre, but would appreciate any help/thoughts.

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of such an option. The best you could do is to use a messaging framework that acts as a broker abstraction (MassTransit, NServiceBus, etc) and swap out the connection string. And even with that approach is not going to be flawless because not all messaging brokers are born equal.

If you cannot introduce an abstraction, you'll need to plan a migration to `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` (latest SDK).

Comment: I feared that was the case, thanks for the answer.